# Today Widget view moves / constraints unstable

Tags: autolayout, today-extension, uistackview, ios9-today-widget

My today widget uses nested stackviews to lay itself out. However, there is slight movement / unintentional resizing when the window is dragged and also when users interact with the view:

[image]

The stackview is simply pinned to all four sides of the super view:

[image]

I'm not sure if I'm missing something specific to Today Widgets, or possibly UIStackview that is causing this movement to occur.

Comment: From what I understand there's a huge bug in Apple's layout process for Today Widgets. No matter how simple the layouts were that I created in the storyboard (or in code), containing only a single label or a single button, there were ALWAYS inconsistencies that would have worked flawless inside the app itself. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37010292/inconsistent-today-widget-behavior-breaks-subviews-height-constraints and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37009679/layout-constraint-conflicts-in-default-today-widget.

Comment: We ended up computing the size of EVERY single subview and setting a height constraint with the computed value for each of the views. Another approach would be not to use Autolayout for the Today Widget at all. I know, it's both brute force methods but we've really tried everything else and there were always issues with regular Autolayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around this by avoiding the use of **pins** on my view (i.e. pinning it 0 points from any side of its super view).

Rather, I rely on other types of constraints. For example, setting my view to **share trailing edges** or **leading edges** with its superview, rather than pinning it 0 points to either side of the superview.

Also handy is using **equal widths** w/ an adjusted multiplier for more flexibility.

Without any pins, the view no longer jerks / resizes unexpectedly. I recommend testing on a device, as it seems to sometimes slip up on the simulator but not on the device.